# Log In Form not interacting with MySQL

Tags: javascript, php, html, mysql, authentication

I am working on a project for a company, its a requirement on our school. I have started developing it using Xampp, with apache as WS and mysql as DS, and I never had a problem with it. Time came that I needed to purchase a web hosting and domain name and so I did, I transferred all my html and php files on my web hosting, and also the database on "phpMyAdmin", its more like of a front end dbms..

For my problem, I cant sign in on my index page but in my localhost I can, I uploaded my site and now I can't sign in on my login form. I don't know why, so I came in here to sought some advice or help from you pros.

Heres my login code:

index.php

`<form action="" method="POST">
<center><h1>Log In</h1><input type ="textbox" name ="ID" placeholder="ID Number">
<input type ="password" name ="pass" placeholder="Password"><input type="submit" name= "btnSubmit" value="Log-in">
</form>`

```
 <?php
if(isset($_POST['btnSubmit']))
{
    $user = $_POST['ID'];
    $pass = $_POST['pass'];
    $x=strlen($user);
    if($user=="")
        echo "<script language='javascript'> window.alert('Input Username.') </script>";
    else if($pass=="")
        echo "<script language='javascript'> window.alert('Input Password.') </script>";
    else if($x=="3")
    {
        include('mysql_connect.php');
        $query="SELECT * from client where clientid='$user' AND clientpw='$pass'";
        $result=@mysql_query($query);
        $row=mysql_fetch_array($result,MYSQL_NUM);
        mysql_close();
        if($row)
        {
            session_start();
            $_SESSION['login'] = 'client';              
            header('location:clienthome.php?id='.$user);
        }
        else                
            echo "<script language='javascript'> window.alert('Invalid Username and/or Password.') </script>";
    }
    else if($x=="2")
    {   
        include('mysql_connect.php');
        $query="SELECT * from admin where ID_Number='$user' AND Password='$pass'";
        $result=@mysql_query($query);
        $row=mysql_fetch_array($result,MYSQL_NUM);

        mysql_close();
        if($row)
        {
            session_start();
            $_SESSION['login'] = 'admin';
            header('location:adminhome.php?id='.$user);

        }
        else                
            echo "<script language='javascript'> window.alert('Invalid Username and/or Password.') </script>";
    }
    else if($x=="4")
    {   
        include('mysql_connect.php');
        $query="SELECT * from supervisor where supervisorid='$user' AND supervisorpw='$pass'";
        $result=@mysql_query($query);
        $row=mysql_fetch_array($result,MYSQL_NUM);

        mysql_close();
        if($row)
        {
            session_start();
            $_SESSION['login'] = 'sup';
            header('location:suphome.php?id='.$user);

        }
        else                
            echo "<script language='javascript'> window.alert('Invalid Username and/or Password.') </script>";
    }
    else if($x=="5")
    {   
        include('mysql_connect.php');
        $query="SELECT * from employee where ID_Number='$user' AND Password='$pass'";
        $result=@mysql_query($query);
        $row=mysql_fetch_array($result,MYSQL_NUM);
        mysql_close();
        if($row)
        {

            session_start();
            $_SESSION['login'] = 'emphome';
            header('location:emphome.php?id='.$user);   
        }
        else                
            echo "<script language='javascript'> window.alert('Invalid Username and/or Password.') </script>";
    }
    else if($x=="6")
    {   
        include('mysql_connect.php');
        $query="SELECT * from external where ID_Numbrer='$user' AND Password='$pass'";
        $result=@mysql_query($query);
        $row=mysql_fetch_array($result,MYSQL_NUM);
        mysql_close();
        if($row)
        {

            session_start();
            $_SESSION['login'] = 'exhome';
            header('location:exhome.php?id='.$user);
        }
        else                
            echo "<script language='javascript'> window.alert('Invalid Username and/or Password.') </script>";
    }
}
```

?>

Comment: If you said you just started, well start learning the correct way. First, use PDO or mysqli_ driver. Use PHP manual: htttp://php.net AND most of all, stop using @ to suppress error messages, read and love them and learn to code so that they do not appear. And what goes into your code, we cant tell where you are wrong because... you are not showing us the error message you are getting.

Comment: What @SiimKallari said, and also sanitize the POST inputs before you put them into a SQL query. Otherwise you are vulnerable to SQL injections.

Comment: This looks like you store the passwords inside the database. It is one of the most important general principles for security to _never store passwords!_ What you store is a _hash_ of a password, then at authentication time you compare that to a hash created from the password specified at runtime. That way no one can steal your users passwords from your server, since they are not stored. Take care to use a good and salted hash algorithm. There are many good examples for that on the internet.

Comment: I'm sorry for my unclear question, actually I can't call it an error, I just can not log in to my log in page when I uploaded it on my web hosting, but when I am accessing it at my localhost which is xampp, it works well.

Comment: And I can't understand your suggestions though since what my code is what I have learned, college student here.

Comment: @George Mañibo `@mysql_query($query)` the @ symbol in this statement will suppress any error messages generated by this. Remove all the @'s, run the code then come back and tell us what error message is generated.
If you have any @'s in mysql_connect.php remove them too.

Comment: @Verox Thank you so much for replying. Still can't login though I got the database and tables and records right on my back end. But on my localhost it do works. Don't know why.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Check what you have in your mysql_connect.php that you are using the correct username and password to connect to your mysql database. On your development localhost you probably connect with the root user, but you can't use that on your webserver. In the cPanel or whatever you have to configure your web site, add a user (with select/insert/delete access) and allow it to connect to your database. Use that user's credentials in your mysql_connect.php.

Comment: Thank you very much for your response.

Comment: At first I came up with a improvised solution, so yeah. As of now I'm having a problem on importing excel file to mysql, which is the excel file was extracted from our biometrics containing the attendance data. If  you got a tip, please email me, thanks again.